qemu system -86 _64 error in Android Studio
[Imageenter image description here of Error](https://i.sstatic.net/6HIRHssB.png)
What i can do for this error while i open an emulator on android studio.
I Reinstall the application and other try but this is not working.
Latest version of Android studio September 2024.
Pixel 8 and 35 version.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
